# Button doesn't stay pressed when in Collection View

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an app with this code

```
    _pushButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _pushButton.frame = CGRectMake(15, 2, 74, 74);
    [_pushButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(buttonPushed:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [_pushButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(buttonReleased:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [_pushButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_pushButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

The behavior is that when the button is pressed the image gets darker and the button stays in that state until the button is released. The buttonPushed is called when the button is pressed and the buttonReleased is called when it is released.

That is what I expected.

I have another application with exactly the same code, that I have copied from the first.
The behavior is different: when the button is pushed, the image gets darker but about a second later the button gets to its original state even if it is still pressed. Only the buttonPushed is called.

This is not what I need.

1) Why the two apps has a different behavior?

2) How can configure the button in the second application to have the same behavior of the first?

**UPDATE**

- In the first app the button is created in a class which subclass
  UIView
- In the second app the button is created in a class which
  subclass UIViewController

**UPDATE 2**

The button which doesn't stay pressed is in a subview of a UICollectionViewCell. Apparently, buttons have a different behaviour when in a cell of a collection view.

Comment: Is the image 2.png the darker one?

Comment: No, it's not. In this case it's the same.